# Issues with toggling an class with javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm creating my first little project and I'm having a button toggle a class on an element. When I use the toggle I can see in the browser that chrome shows as if it changed but it changes to the same thing that's on it right now. I've even tried toggling a different random class onto it and cannot get it to toggle that on or off. Not quite sure what I'm doing wrong.

Heres my javascript:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".open").forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    event.target
     .parentElement
     .parentElement
     .parentElement
     .parentElement
     .children[1]
     .classList.toggle("hidden");
  });
});
```

And my HTML code

```html
<div class="search-container">
  <ul class="blade-list">
    <li class="blade">
      <div class="title">
        <h1 class="blade-material">27574-10</h1>
        <div class="buttons">
          <button class="open" id="open1">
            <img
              class="open"
              id="open1"
              src="img/svg/plus-empty.svg"
              alt="Expand specs"
            />
          </button>
          <button class="print" id="print1">
            <img
              class="print"
              id="print1"
              src="img/svg/printer-empty.svg"
              alt="Print"
            />
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div
        class="specs-container hidden"
        id="specs-container-1"
      ></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: *I can see in the browser that chrome shows as if it changed but it changes to the same thing that's on it right now* - I can't understand that

Comment: What is the css for `hidden`?

Comment: Which element are you targetting with `event.target
     .parentElement
     .parentElement
     .parentElement
     .parentElement
     .children[1]`?

Comment: I think is best to use another `querySelector`/`.closest()` instead of `.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement` if the structure is always the same (also for performance) like the @mister jojo answer

Comment: Whatever is being targetted can be seen by copying this code into an editor of your choice and then clicking the buttons, logging the element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `querySelectorAll(".open")` which will select both `<button class="open"> ... </button>` and the image inside `<img class="open" ... \>`
This means that when you click the button, the event is fired twice (one for the button, one for the image).
The code which toggles the class is actually correct, but it toggles twice which means there's no effect
Here is the fixed HTML

```html
<div class="search-container">
  <ul class="blade-list">
    <li class="blade">
      <div class="title">
        <h1 class="blade-material">27574-10</h1>
        <div class="buttons">
          <button class="open" id="open1">
            <img
              id="open1"
              src="img/svg/plus-empty.svg"
              alt="Expand specs"
            />
          </button>
          <button class="print" id="print1">
            <img
              class="print"
              id="print1"
              src="img/svg/printer-empty.svg"
              alt="Print"
            />
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div
        class="specs-container hidden"
        id="specs-container-1"
      ></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

If you plan to do the same thing with the `print` button/img then make sure to remove `class="print"` from it aswell.

Comment: That would make sense on why I would see in the dev tools for chrome that it changes it. I got it to work I just did querySelectorALl("img.open"). Thank you!

Comment: If it works, make sure to mark as correct (the checkmark)

Answer (score 1):

certainly, something like this would be preferable

```
document.querySelectorAll("button.open").forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener("click", event => {
    event
      .currentTarget.closest(".title") // currentTarget
      .nextElementSibling
      .classList.toggle("hidden");
  });
});
```

Comment: No need to add the listener to the images; just add them to `button.open` querySelector results only.